# Date range issue in pandas python

Tags: python, date, pandas, date-range, datetimeindex

I tried this:

```
pd.date_range(2000, periods = 365, freq = 'D',format = '%d-%m-%Y')
```

why I am getting this result:

```
DatetimeIndex(['1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002', '1970-01-02 00:00:00.000002',
               '1970-01-03 00:00:00.000002', '1970-01-04 00:00:00.000002',
               '1970-01-05 00:00:00.000002', '1970-01-06 00:00:00.000002',
               '1970-01-07 00:00:00.000002', '1970-01-08 00:00:00.000002',
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add `''` to `2000` only:

```
print (pd.date_range('2000', periods = 365, freq = 'D'))

DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-03', '2000-01-04',
               '2000-01-05', '2000-01-06', '2000-01-07', '2000-01-08',
               '2000-01-09', '2000-01-10',
               ...
               '2000-12-21', '2000-12-22', '2000-12-23', '2000-12-24',
               '2000-12-25', '2000-12-26', '2000-12-27', '2000-12-28',
               '2000-12-29', '2000-12-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=365, freq='D')
```

If use `int`, cast it to `str`:

```
print (pd.date_range(str(2000), periods = 365, freq = 'D'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods = 365, freq = 'D',format = '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: is it possible to generate date_range if we only provide 2000 instead of 1/1/2000??